# AWS s3 create pre signed post does not work on deploy

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework, pre-signed-url

I am creating presigned url using aws-sdk’s nodejs/createPresignedPost method. Its all working via serverless-offline plugin on my local, cause my personal accesskey has all accesses. But when I deploy it via serverless framework it errors out with HTTP 403 and the error in browser reads as follows

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

The key starts with ASIA `ASIAQDGRI5OSPEXMAPLE`
I have granted all action permission to my lambda on target bucket.

My Api gateway and lambdas that return the signed url are in ‘us-east-1’ region and the bucket is in ‘ap-south-1’ region.

I am sure I am missing some IAM permissions but I can not figure it our. Can some one help me here?

Here is my function that returns a promise on getting pre signed post url

```
  function getSignedUploadUrl() {
    const params = {
        Expires: 600,
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Fields: {
          key: s3FilePathKey,
          acl: acl,
          "content-type": contentType,
        },
        conditions: [
          { acl: acl },
          { "content-type": contentType },
          ["content-length-range", 1000000, 75000000],
        ],
      };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const s3 = new S3({
        region: AWS_REGION
      });
      s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject({
            message: "Something went wrong",
          });
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you post the code related?

Comment: @jellycsc Added it to the question

Comment: I am facing a very similar problem. I've put the values returned by `createPresignedPost` in a `form`, my lambda, api gateway and S3 bucket are all in the same `eu-west-1` region. The access key id I get also starts with `ASIA`, if that's relevant.

Comment: Even My problem was not solved I eventually moved all my AWS resources to us-east-1 region lambda, S3 bucket etc. @MarcelloRomani And it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Eventually I realised I was doing two errors: 1) I was putting the return values from `createPresignedPost` in a `form` manually, which lead to errors. Those went away when I did it programmatically (with some simple templating). 2) When testing the URL _outside_ of the lambda function I was using the wrong AWS_PROFILE.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani I get the second point and I was debugging in that direction only. How ever I did not quite get the first point. Can you share some code snippet. By manually you mean via curl or postman?  I did not do ithat I was directly adding the values to formdata which I was posting to S3 url

Comment: I wasn't clear on point 1). I had a lambda similar to yours, which returned a JSON containing `url` and `fields` then I had a file upload `form` where I was copy-pasting the key/value pairs in the `fields` dict. The point I'm tryuing to make is that the manual copy/paste led to errors (I thought I was careful but then...) And yes, I was calling the lambda via Postman (through an API GW endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

The fields to include in the formdata varies based on where the code is run, at least that was the case in my problem. In Elastic Beanstalk environment, there was an additional `x-amz-security-token` field (alongside the `AWSAccessKeyId`, `key` etc), which was not present in the fields returned by Boto3 `create_presigned_post` while run on local env.

Comment: Thats wierd ideally create_presigned_post should retrun all form data that needs to be passed while using the signed url.